# Is there a one line way to include multiple views in laravel 5 - blade?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade

I would like to know if its possible to load multiple views in a single line, for example:

```
@include('view1','view2','view3')
```

or i have to do this always:

```
@include('view1')
@include('view2')
@include('view3')
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there isn't.

If you really have a lot of views to include you could do this though:

```
@foreach(['view1', 'view2', 'view3'] as $view)
    @include($view)
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks, this applies for "@yield()" too right?, if the $view value doesn't exist in the template will the app go down?

Comment: Yes and yes. If you want to check if the view exists first, you can wrap the `@include` in `@if(View::exists($view))`